# PySpark: compute cumsum over a window that counts back

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, cumsum

I have a dataframe with dates and days_diff values already computed. 
The **aim** is to extract every date that:
- has a **days_diff value > 90**
- has a **cumulated days_diff value > 90**

II thought a cumsum computation would be needed. So what we want to do is:
Apply a cumsum operation on days_diff but it should counts back when the cumsum reaches a specific number.

I'll provide almost the same data than I use. Let's fix this limit to 90 and create our dataframe:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.Window import *

limit = 90
# We'll try to find it with a null value that shouldn't bother us
values = [(1, '2018-12-26', 7), (1, '2018-12-19', 5), (1, '2018-12-14', 38),
        (1, '2018-11-06', 10), (1, '2018-10-27', 61), (1, '2018-08-27', 17), 
       (1, '2018-08-10', 37), (1, '2018-07-04', 1), (1, '2018-07-03', 1), 
       (1, '2018-07-02', 3), (1, '2018-06-29', 51), (1, '2018-05-09', 5), 
       (1, '2018-05-04', 22), (1, '2018-04-12', 58), (1, '2018-02-13', 13)
       (1, '2018-01-31', None)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(values, ['id', 'date', 'days_diff']).orderBy('date')
df.show()
+---+----------+---------+
| id|      date|days_diff|
+---+----------+---------+
|  1|2018-01-31|     null|
|  1|2018-02-13|       13|
|  1|2018-04-12|       58|
|  1|2018-05-04|       22|
|  1|2018-05-09|        5|
|  1|2018-06-29|       51|
|  1|2018-07-02|        3|
|  1|2018-07-03|        1|
|  1|2018-07-04|        1|
|  1|2018-08-10|       37|
|  1|2018-08-27|       17|
|  1|2018-10-27|       61|
|  1|2018-11-06|       10|
|  1|2018-12-14|       38|
|  1|2018-12-19|        5|
|  1|2018-12-26|        7|
+---+----------+---------+
```

Here's a way I found to compute the cumsum over days_diff:

```
win_spec = (Window.orderBy('id', 'date').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))
df_cum = df.withColumn('days_diff_cumsum', sum(df.days_diff).over(win_spec))
```

It gives us:

```
+---+----------+---------+----------------+
| id|      date|days_diff|diff_days_cumsum|
+---+----------+---------+----------------+
|  1|2018-01-31|     null|            null|
|  1|2018-02-13|       13|              13|
|  1|2018-04-12|       58|              71|
|  1|2018-05-04|       22|              93|
|  1|2018-05-09|        5|              98|
|  1|2018-06-29|       51|             149|
|  1|2018-07-02|        3|             152|
|  1|2018-07-03|        1|             153|
|  1|2018-07-04|        1|             154|
|  1|2018-08-10|       37|             191|
|  1|2018-08-27|       17|             208|
|  1|2018-10-27|       61|             269|
|  1|2018-11-06|       10|             279|
|  1|2018-12-14|       38|             317|
|  1|2018-12-19|        5|             322|
|  1|2018-12-26|        7|             329|
+---+----------+---------+----------------+
```

Does anyone have an idea to go further ?